# JavaScript Setting JSON element pointed by path

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a function which modify a value in my JSON object. The value is specified by path like in this example example:

```
setConfigItem(['node1','nodeA','value1A'], 1234);
```

Currently I am using a following function:

```
var setConfigItem = function(path, value) {
    if (path.length == 1)
        config[path[0]] = value;
    if (path.length == 2)
        config[path[0]][path[1]] = value;
    if (path.length == 3)
        config[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = value;

    // ...

    throw {name : "NotImplementedError", message : "too lazy to implement more"}; 
}
```

What would be a better and generic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple imperative solution:

```js
const obj = {a: {b: {c: 1}}}

function updateAt(object, path, value) {
  let o = object;
  for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
    if(i < path.length - 1){
      o = o[path[i]];
    }
    else{
      o[path[i]] = value;
    }
  }
}

updateAt(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: All the questions were very good but I chosen yours as the most elegant one. I like the iterative approach

Answer (score 3):

Simple recursive solution

```js
var config = {node1: {nodeA: {value1A: 0}}};

function setConfigItem(config, path, value) {
  if (path.length == 1) {
    config[path[0]] = value;
  } else {
    setConfigItem(config[path[0]], path.slice(1), value);
  }
}

setConfigItem(config, ['node1','nodeA','value1A'], 1234);

console.log(config);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but you should probably slice the path array instead of shifting the value as you will be mutating the provided array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#reduce` to set your value dynamically using your path array.

Reduce will fold an array to a single value, we are seeding the reduce function with our object so each iteration we return `currentObject[key]` until we get to our desired key where we set the value.

```js
const config = {
  node1: {
    nodeA: {
      value1A: 4657
    }
  }
}

const setConfigItem = (path, value, obj) => {
  // reduce the path array, each iteration dig further into the object properties
  path.reduce((accumulator, key, i) => {
    // if you are at the final key set the value
    if (i === path.length - 1) {
      accumulator[key] = value
      return accumulator
    }
    // test to see if there is a property
    if (typeof accumulator[key] === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('Nothing to see here')
    }
    // return the next level down
    return accumulator[key]
  }, obj)
  // return the original object
  return obj
}

console.log('before', config)

setConfigItem(['node1','nodeA','value1A'], 1234, config)

console.log('after', config)

expect('mutate given object with value', () => {
  const obj = { a: 1 }
  assert(setConfigItem(['a'], 2, obj)).deepEqual({ a: 2 })
  assert(setConfigItem(['a'], 2, obj)).strictEqual(obj)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/KyQQmL.js"></script>
```

Comment: I very like your solution. I used it for reading instead of setting as it allows to modify it to single line: `path.reduce((node, key) => node[key], object)`. For setting I used iterative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) from Lodash:

```js
let object = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } };
_.set(object, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 5);
console.log(object);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```